# Fortran module procedure outside module

Tags: module, fortran

I found nothing in Google, so...

I try to use all objected-oriented features of Fortran 90 and create module for some specific work (like class in C++). I have written something like this:

```
module test

integer, PRIVATE :: dummy
PUBLIC :: sub

contains 

subroutine sub()
dummy = 1
end subroutine sub

end module test
```

But, I have about 10 such subroutines and it's very bad idea to place them all into one file. Is it possible to tell compiler, that `sub` is module subroutine, but place it in another file? Because, it looks like this code will be compiled only if I define body of `sub` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct answer to your question - yes - you can use a `INCLUDE` line to reference a file that contains the definition of `sub` from within the file that contains the definition of the rest of the module (the include line for the files with the subroutine code would come after the `CONTAINS` statement in the module.

```
MODULE test
  INTEGER, PRIVATE :: dummy
  PUBLIC :: sub
CONTAINS
  INCLUDE 'sub.f90'
END MODULE test

! sub.f90
SUBROUTINE sub
  dummy = 1
END SUBROUTINE sub
```

However, this is an atypical arrangement.  Further, if it is a "very bad idea to place them all into one file", then is it a good idea (or necessary) to have the presumably disparate subroutines available from the one module?

The more conventional F90 solution is for the shared data (dummy) to be placed in one "low level" module as public entities, to place the subroutine definitions into a series of "intermediate level" modules that use the low level module as required, and then for a final "high level" module that uses the intermediate modules and provide a collective export to client code.  Source code conventions, rather than language rules, are then used to avoid client code from directly using the intermediate and low level modules.

```
MODULE low_level_shared
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PUBLIC :: dummy
END MODULE low_level_shared

MODULE intermediate_sub1
  IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE sub1
     USE low_level_shared
     dummy = 1
   END SUBROUTINE sub1
END MODULE intermediate_sub1

MODULE intermediate_sub2
  IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE sub2
     USE low_level_shared
     ...
   END SUBROUTINE sub2
END MODULE intermediate_sub2

MODULE high_level
  USE intermediate_sub1
  USE intermediate_sub2
  PRIVATE
  PUBLIC :: sub1, sub2
END MODULE high_level

PROGRAM client_code
  USE high_level
  ...
  CALL sub1
END PROGRAM client_code
```

Fortran 2008 allows additional structures and control through the submodule feature, where module procedures interfaces can be defined in a separate program unit to the module procedure implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately subroutines are huge, because it is one of the physical simulations modules. It looks like, that i have to use INCLUDE. Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from using the layered module approach?

Comment: Because all subroutines are logically on identical level - they all work on some data, but make different physical operations on it. So, layered model will be looked far-fetched. But thank you for the idea. Do you know some real disadvantages of INCLDUE method?

Comment: INCLUDE simply dumps the contents of the INCLUDEd file into the source file. If you use an IDE you probably won't be able to add the INCLUDEd file to the project, but it will still get compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I don't know if it is  good, but it is possible. You can use `include "filename"` or if you use a prepocessor also `#include "filename"`.

This way you include the text from any other file in the place of the `include` statement. But it is debatable, if it is a positive thing because 10 procedures in one file is usually not too much, if they are not extremely long (and you should change them then probably).

(I must be careful, last time I mentioned include is possible I was strongly overvoted by people not liking it.)

Also note, that Fortran 2003 brings much more object orientation including type-bound procedures, taht may be worth to consider, if you need more instances of your object.

Comment: I know such possibility. But it is very bad rogramming style, i try to avoid it. Good way is 'interface' blocks, but they are not allowed after 'contains'.

Comment: No, interface blocks are not good style. There are very few cases where you should actually use them. Especially do not use them, where you can use modules. They are good for interfacing legacy libraries or C code. Also for generic interfaces, but you do not use full procedure headers there.